# How to remove % Symobols from white spaces when saving to Document Directory

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am trying to rename my PDF to 'My Document 1.pdf' but when I enter this name it saves the whitespaces as '%' symbols and the output would be 'My%Document%1.pdf'. As a result I am unable to export it to any of the apps as the name cannot be read...

I am using a Alert Controller with a text field to enter the name.
Here is the code used to enter the name.

I declared this as a global variable so that I could access this anywhere.

```
var pdfnameing = "PDFfile"
```

This is the function called when the naming button is pressed

```
 func PDFNaming()  {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Name Your PDF", message: "Enter A Name for your PDF", preferredStyle: .alert)

                 // add textfield at index 0
                 alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: {(_ textField: UITextField) -> Void in
                     textField.placeholder = "PDF Name"

                 })

              

                 // Alert action confirm
                 let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                    // print("name: \(String(describing: alertController.textFields?[0].text))")
                     //print("email: \(String(describing: alertController.textFields?[1].text))")
                  
                  
                    self.pdfnameing = alertController.textFields![0].text!
               
                 
                 })
                 alertController.addAction(confirmAction)

                 // Alert action cancel
                 let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                     print("Canelled")
                  self.customm.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
                 })
                 alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

                 // Present alert controller
                 present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Saving the PDF

```
 let fullPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).appendingPathComponent("\(pdfnameing).pdf").absoluteString
```

Any Help Would Be Much Appreciated.
Thanks In Advance!

Comment: `absoluteString` it is not a path. Just use url `path` property.

Comment: Note that the result of absoluteString would be `"My%20Document%201.pdf"` not `"My%Document%1.pdf"`because it is percent encoding your spaces replacing the whitespaces with `"%20"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong `URL` property. What you need is to use the URL `path` property which won't percent encode your string and won't include the `URL` scheme.